# Generate Mst response tool

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I am trying to create a tool using c# to get the properties generated from clicking through the dialogs of an msi(windows installer).

I can get the final msi properties by reading the _property table before the msi closes but this contains quite a number of properties that are not required e.g.  directories etc.

What i would like to be able to do is just launch the dialogs and get the populated properties relating to those dialogs. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks
B

Comment: How are you accessing the _Property table? I haven't made it that far. I can't seem to find a way to have both a handle the the database and run the installer with a GUI at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of helping, and since nobody else has answered, I will just write what I know, though it isn't really an answer in a technical sense.

There are several tools available that already do this - some even used to be free but the downloads were removed (`Wise InstallTailor`).

**I don't know what your use-case really is**. If you just want a solution for a specific task, or you are intending to code this yourself despite other solutions being available?

---

**Wise Package Studio** had one transform generator called **InstallTailor**. I don't think it is freely distributable as the product has been taken off the market and bought up (or we could have shared the EXE - it used to be freeware as far as I recall).

**InstallAware** has a feature called **InstallAware Transformer**:
https://www.installaware.com/installtailor.htm

**Advanced Installer** has a feature to create a "**Response Transform**" which is essentially doing the same as InstallAware transformer with slight variations.

**Installshield** has a **transform project type** which offers pretty much exactly the same features as the other two products by the looks of it.

---

The above are all commercial products, but some of these features may work after the trial period has expired. I cannot guarantee it, but it looks like Advanced Installer allows a response transform to be generated freely.

So that is a non-technical answer for you. Perhaps you just need to get a tool to do the job?