# Create MSI Transform to add registry value

Tags: windows-installer, agent, orca, scom

I am a SCOM Administrator trying to modify the MOMAgent.msi installation using Super Orca to create a transform file.
My aim is to modify the value of MaximumQueueSizeKB property from the default value (15360) to 76800.

Strangely enough the property already exists in the MSI and the default value is already there, but running a search on the property name returns no other results, so this leads me to believe that the property isn't being referenced and simply setting the value of the property to 76800 and then trying an install doesn't change the registry value that it relates to, it just stays at the default value, so again this leads me to believe the property is not being used.

I can't see anything in the registry table of the MSI that relates to 'maximumQueueSizeKb' either, yet the value is somehow written during install.

I have googled and trawled through many different articles that relate to this registry key but they all refer to editing the key after installation. We push the agent out during the build process so want it to be set during installation and it would work better for us to be done this way.

I've got some experience modifying MSI files but not enough to know how to modify it to add the registry value in during install without being instructed on how to do so.

If someone could provide instruction on how to do this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have some answers on this. All I could find right now was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55034008/129130). Give it a try and I will look back later. Or try commercial tools [Advanced Installer or Installshield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) to make the transform. Also, you might have more luck on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) (system administrator site), or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) (power user site) for this type of question.

Comment: [Registry table group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/registry-tables-group). Add an entry in the registry table (or modify one) and link it to a component if it is not linked already. Should work, but always something...